# invalid token on discord,.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've recently started a new discord.js bot, and got an 'invalid token' error. it cannot be because of an *async* function, because I've only started the bot and I have 0 commands, last time this has happened was when I was trying to host another bot on heroku.i have never found a solution to, here's my terminal:

```
C:\Users\Lory\Desktop\pp>node .
(node:3760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\Lory\Desktop\pp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:133:26)
    at Client.login (C:\Users\Lory\Desktop\pp\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:222:21)
(node:3760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3760) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

C:\Users\Lory\Desktop\pp>
```

The code that I am using:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '!'

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot is ready');

});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: Have you changed `'token'` with the token that you got from [Discord](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications)?

Answer (score 9):

The `An invalid token was provided` error is given because the token you have set in `.login()` is not valid or revoked by Discord for several reasons like spam, malicious behaviour or inactivity. Also make sure you have your own bot application created in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers). To generate a bot token follow these steps:

1. Go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers)
2. Click on your application you have made (If you don't have one, create a new one).
3. If everything is set, on the menu on the left under settings, click on `Bot`.

If you see this:
[image]

Just click on `Add Bot`.

4. On this page you can set an avatar, username and regenerate a token. Click on `Regenerate` and then `copy`. Paste the token in `client.login('Paste the copied token here')`.
5. Run your script
6. Enjoy!

Comment: i already have the bot,and this isn't my first time making one.what is a revoked token?

Comment: @c.ales a revoked token is a token that has been made unusable by Discord for several reasons: inactivity, spam or malicious behaviour. Just regenerate a new token for your bot and you should be good to go.

Comment: ive tried making other bots and regenerating token,but still tells me i have an invalid token at a websocket

Comment: @c.ales Have you tried reinstalling discord.js again? Also tested with a different bot?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you revokeded it ! Lot of people like the revoke button and still don't know what it does.

So next time try to grab the token and maybe just to be sure make `/*`  between the entire code just to hide it for a moment `*/`
and use this normal example :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () =>{
console.log('FINALLYYYYYY')
})

client.login('the token')
```

If it still doesn't work. Then the problem is comming from somewhere else. Maybe you changed the discord module text and forgot it or maybe a module installed discord.js and changed it so that it fits them ? Try reinstalling discord.js and node.js alone